# How to add custom header to PHP mail?

Tags: php, email

I have a mail function with the standard parameters:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Where:

```
$headers = "From: admin@mysite.org";
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-".$random_hash."\"";
```

Now, I'm trying to get the sent e-mails to show 'My Site' as the sender instead of 'admin@mysite.org' but if someone responds to the mail it still needs to go to admin@mysite.org.

I've tried putting "My Site" in the "From" field before and after the e-mail address but it just appends to the address. I've tried appending it to the $headers variable but that messes the whole e-mail up. I've also tried adding it this way:

```
$headers .= "\r\nMy Site";
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I know this can't be complicated as I've seen it done a hundred times, but I can't seem to find a straight-forward answer for this - how do I 'mask' the admin e-mail with the site name but still keep it as the address any response goes to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `From:` header to `"From: My Site <admin@mysite.org>"`

```
$headers = "From: My Site <admin@mysite.org>";
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-".$random_hash."\"";
```

From the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3135).

Comment: And that's all there is to it. Thanks, that solves this issue. I'll accept your answer in 7 minutes:)

Answer (score 0):

There is the `"From: something <something@something.com>";` header, and then there is also the optional fifth parameter of `mail()` which allows you to override the from setting that may or may not be set in `php.ini`.

```
<?php
  $to = 'name@domain.com.au';
  $header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
  $header .= "From: Name <noreply@domain.info>" . "\r\n";
  $fifthp = '-f noreply@domain.info';
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $header,$fifthp);
?>
```